# CRA to Vite Migration

Tags: reactjs, frontend, migration, create-react-app, vite

I have react app and I've tried to migrate it to vite. After I completed the process  the following error came up

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at html-message.js:2:1
```

My main concern is that the html-message.js doesn't exist in my project or at least in my files. I also try to search the node_modules without any lack. Also, this is the source code of the file according to the browser's inspect:

```
import InAppMessage from './in-app-message.js';
export default class HtmlMessage extends InAppMessage {
  constructor(l, u, n, e, r, s, t, i, o, a, c) {
    super(
      l,
      null,
      null,
      u,
      n,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      (e = e || InAppMessage.DismissType.MANUAL),
      r,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      s,
      t,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      i,
      void 0,
      void 0,
      void 0,
      o,
      a
    ),
      (this.messageFields = c);
  }
  ll() {
    return !1;
  }
  k(l) {
    if (this.Ce === InAppMessage.es.ul) {
      if (this.nl) return !1;
      this.nl = !0;
    }
    return this.lt.St(l), !0;
  }
}
```

I found out that the error came from braze but still I don't know how to solve it. Does anyone know how I should approach this?

Answer (score 1):

My friend, this is the answer we have been looking for: https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/web/initial_sdk_setup/#ssr

> If you use Vite and see a warning around circular dependencies or Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null, you may need to exclude the Braze SDK from its dependency discovery:

```
optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['@braze/web-sdk']
},
```

Comment: Absolute life saver @Cajotafer, didn't think to look in the Braze docs themselves!!